# Make fluid simulation go up instead of down

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

Hello, I want to make it seem like my fluid is coming from the well and overflowing...

so far

1. I've tried hiding the flow/fluid emitter object into the well but the fluid doesn't go beyond the brim of the well. Even after increasing the size of the sphere
2. I've also tried using a circle that's slightly extruded as the flow object. But it doesn't work. Is this right? Should it work or am I limited to a few shapes

New to blender, kindly help

Comment: Your well is leaking and most of the fluid is going out through the leaks. try putting an open cylinder just inside the well and making it invisible in renders but also an effector object in your animation if you don't want that.

Comment: Thank you!! I actually thought the leaking added a nice touch so I'll keep it. But the info on adding an invisible object is definitely noted. Might use it in a different sim

Comment: I like it too.  There should be some easier way to increase the total flow, but I've never figured out what it is.

Answer (score 2):

To make something like this...

[image]

...you can try following these steps:

Add a cylinder, delete the top face, give it a solidify modifier.

Add an icosphere, put it in the cylinder without touching it and select your icosphere -> objects -> quick effect -> quick liquid

Change flow behaviour to inflow, check initial velocity, set 10 to z

On the domain change resolution to 100, uncheck all border collisions so that you "see" something. You can change that later.
Check "mesh".

Select your cylinder and physics "fluid" -> type: Effector

Hint: the gif is just an EEVEE render -> Water looks best rendered with Cycles.

blend file to check:

[image]

Limitation: Unfortunately Blender fluid cannot "raise water". So if you make an inflow inside of something, the water will never grow higher than your inflow.

So if you wanna make a "kind of" overflowing i would try with a low z velocity. This should "kind of" work for you.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll see how I can apply this to my scene